# func return list<int> with args (int arry[int], int array[int])

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

my problem is:

this algorithm work i think... but Visual Studio 2013 gives me this error:

C2893 unknown-type std::less::operator()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) const.

i have to create a func that take 2 arrays of int and return a list with the elements of the arrays, sorted and without elements who repeat in the series into the list.

```
    list<int> sort_array(int *elenco1[C], int *elenco2[C])
{
    list<int> merge1;
    list<int> merge2;

    for (int i = 0; i < C; ++i)
    {
        merge1.push_back(*elenco1[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < C; ++i)
    {
        merge2.push_back(*elenco2[i]);
    }

    merge1.sort();
    merge2.sort();

    merge1.merge(merge2);

    merge1.sort();

    list<int>::iterator inizio = merge1.begin();
    list<int>::iterator fine = merge1.end();

    for (inizio; inizio != fine; ++inizio)
    {
        for (fine; fine != inizio; --fine)
        {
            if (*fine == *inizio)
            {
                merge1.erase(inizio);
            }
            else{}
        }
    }

    return merge1;
}

int main()
{
    list<int> stampa;

    int* elenco1[C];
    int* elenco2[C];

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < C; ++k)
        {
            *elenco1[k] = i;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 5; i <= 9; ++i)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < C; ++k)
        {
            *elenco1[k] = i;
        }
    }

    stampa = sort_array(elenco1, elenco2);

    list<int>::iterator inizio = stampa.begin();
    list<int>::iterator fine = stampa.end();

    for (inizio; inizio != fine; ++inizio)
    {
        cout << *inizio << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're really set on doing things in as difficult a way as possible, use some standard algorithms (and probably `std::vector` instead of `list`). The specific algorithms you care about are `std::sort` and `std::unique`.

The basic idea is to create a vector containing the elements of both input vectors. Sort that, then use `std::unique` to remove duplicates. Code could look vaguely like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<int> 
merge_sort_unique(std::vector<int> in1, std::vector<int> const &in2) {
    in1.insert(in1.end(), in2.begin(), in2.end());
    std::sort(in1.begin(), in1.end());
    in1.erase(std::unique(in1.begin(), in1.end()), in1.end());
    return in1;
}
```

And here's a quick demo of using this:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> in1{ 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1 };
    std::vector<int> in2{ 10, 10, 9, 10, 1, 10, 9, 4, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2 };

    std::vector<int> out = merge_sort_unique(in1, in2);

    for (int i : out)
        std::cout << i << "\t";
}
```

One quick note: since we need a copy of the input data, I've started by passing the first argument by value, so that's a copy of one of the inputs. We then copy the content of the other input to the end of that. Then we have a single vector containing all the data, which we can then sort and remove duplicates.

This copying might initially seem wasteful, but unless we're allowed to modify one of the inputs it's really necessary.

And yes, if you're really concerned with saving space, even at the expense of slightly greater algorithmic complexity, you certainly *can* sort first, then remove duplicates from each input, then merge and remove duplicates again. If you expect to have a lot of duplicates, this might even be faster--but you'd need a fair amount of knowledge of the input data to be at all certain that it was faster (or even "not slower").

Answer (score 0):

compiles fine here also VS 2013...

your code will not work though because of the arrays of pointers to int. You need arrays of int not arrays of pointer to int

replace

```
int *elenco1[C]
```

with

```
int elenco[C];
```

and drop the asterisk in sort_array

There's more:

```
for (fine; fine != inizio; --fine)
{
   if (*fine == *inizio)
   {
       merge1.erase(inizio);
   }
}
```

Here you are looping with an iterator but also using erase. erase will invalidate the iterator and the loop wont work anymore. erase return a new valid iterator, so better use

```
inizio = merge1.erase(inizio);
```

Comment: u are right, infact i tryed to do it in the 1st time... but the error is the same

Comment: Also of note: `int elenco[C]` in a function argument is the same as `int* elenco` and the `C` part has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: Beware that `erase` is not guaranteed to return a valid iterator on all platforms. In fact, `erase` does not return anything on Solaris and AIX.

Comment: true that, there's more wrong with the code like dereferencing the end iterator (fine) the first time through the loop